# Visual Studio 2015 application not running on another computer

Tags: c#, deployment

I have installed the .NET framework 4.5.2 (which my application targets). But still, the application does not run on any other computer.
When I double click, nothing happens. It runs perfectly fine on my computer.

When I click the Application Manifest file on the other computer, it says that

> "DEPLOYMENT AND APPLICATION DO NOT HAVE MATCHING SECURITY ZONES".

I have followed many steps online before asking the question here, to no avail. Here are the error details:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
Windows             : 6.2.9200.0 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.34209
System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL
clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL
dfshim.dll          : 6.3.9600.16384 (winblue_rtm.130821-1623)

SOURCES
Deployment url          : file:///C:/Users/VAIO/Downloads/Atlas%20Booking%20Manager%20(ABM)_1_0_0_8/Atlas%20Booking%20Manager%20(ABM).application

IDENTITIES
Deployment Identity     : Atlas Booking Manager (ABM).application, Version=1.0.0.8, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1084140fe0278529, processorArchitecture=msil

APPLICATION SUMMARY
* Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* Activation of C:\Users\VAIO\Downloads\Atlas Booking Manager (ABM)_1_0_0_8\Atlas Booking Manager (ABM).application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
    + Deployment and application do not have matching security zones.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
* [4/29/2016 1:36:22 AM] : Activation of C:\Users\VAIO\Downloads\Atlas Booking Manager (ABM)_1_0_0_8\Atlas Booking Manager (ABM).application has started.
* [4/29/2016 1:36:22 AM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
* [4/29/2016 1:36:22 AM] : Installation of the application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [4/29/2016 1:36:22 AM] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (Zone)
    - Deployment and application do not have matching security zones.
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at                     System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
No transaction information is available.
```

I am using OneClick, and have:

1) under publish, checked 'this app is available offline'

2) under security, this is a full trust app

3) under signing, checked "sign the ClickOnce manifests" and 'sign the assembley'

What am I missing? On my development computer it works fine.

Comment: Show some evidence of having googled the error message so we don't have to repeat the existing Q+A about it.  It should then be obvious that you should not omit the browser name you use for example.

Comment: I have used many different browsers and also tried to transfer the application via USB. it does not run on other computers. i have tried many diagnostic suggestions through google such as this article: http://codeketchup.blogspot.ca/2013/06/how-to-fix-deployment-and-application.html

Answer (score 0):

Your file is probably blocked because you downloaded the files from the internet. Go to file properties and in the bottom of the properties screen you can unblock the file (exe) and the execute the files on your system.

[MSDN blog: unblocking downloaded file](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/delay/p/unblockingdownloadedfile/)

Comment: I went to file properties, but there's no option for unblocking the exe. Here's the dropbox file: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zaqlzcmivdtvg17/AADQVjoXWq2fMAaYM0QwasNCa?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It turns out that my software was pointing to a directory which does not exist on the new computer. Silly me! I thought the directory would be created by itself. Well, thanks for your time and help guys. I hope people seeing this could get help with their project too! You can go to Event Viewer in Windows to see exactly what happened.